# Building C# solutions from command line with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, build-process, build-automation

I want to automate the build process for my C# solutions. How can I build C# solutions from the command line so that I don't have to deal with dependencies manually?

Comment: What makes you think that dependencies don't matter when you build on the cmd line?  It is a helluvalot more manual, you'll have to type the full path name to the dependent assembly.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me correctly. All I want is to simply build a C# solution from command line in such a way that (almost) only the path to the solution file is needed and MSBuild seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

if you open a visual studio command prompt from your start menu - then you can call MSBuild and give that either the .sln file or a specific .csproj file in order to build what you need

alternatively you can create a custom MSBuild file that takes care of the tasks.

one tip: make sure the version of MSBuild that you use is applicable to the target framework or tools version of the project

i.e. if you try and build a solution that was created in vs2010 with msbuild 3.5 then it will not recognise the 4.0 toolset of the project

Comment: I had to execute `vcvarsall.bat` before I could get `msbuild` to run from any old cli instance, once I did that it works like a charm!

Comment: You could instead open the "Developer Command Prompt": All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools.

Answer (score 75):

For solutions you can use:

`devenv /build Release Solution.sln`

or

`devenv /build Debug Solution.sln`

Comment: This requires Visual Studio to be installed on the machine executing the build. msbuild is available with .net framework.

Comment: +1. For an unknown reason, msbuild doesn't work on a brand new .sln file generated with `qmake -recursive -tp vc my.sln`. I had to open the solution with VS to get msbuild working. With devenv, I can automate the qmake and build process. Thanks

Comment: I tried this in a batch file, but had to put the line `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`  on top of it. Then it worked. If you have a different edition of VS, you need to change the path to VsDevCmd.bat.

Comment: What if I want to specify output folder path?

Answer (score 22):

Visual Studio project and solution files are also [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) build files.

You can simply run MSBuild against the solution/project file and it will build:

```
<path to>msbuild.exe <path to>solution/project file
```

Answer (score 18):

msbuild YourSolution.sln

Comment: How does it know whether to do a Debug or Release build?

Comment: "msbuild /?" for command line arguments including debug/release

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm a huge fan of Rake (yeah - I heard you when you said your c# solution)

Check it out: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/derickbailey/archive/2009/09/23/albacore-a-suite-of-rake-build-tasks-for-net-solutions.aspx

Have fun - it made life a lot better for me!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the c# (`csc.exe`) compiler directly:

[Command-line building with csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Comment: I think csc.exe only works on .cs files but not on .sln files